# Different behavior from xsl:call-template than xsl:apply-templates?

Tags: xml, xslt

Why is an *xsl:template*'s "list all attributes" behavior different when it is run inline versus being called as a named template?

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
  <car model="Focus" manufacturer="Ford" year="2000" />
  <car model="Golf" manufacturer="Volkswagen" year="1999" />
  <car model="Camry" manufacturer="Toyota" year="1999" />
  <car model="Civic" manufacturer="Honda" year="2000" />
  <car model="Prizm" manufacturer="Chevrolet" year="2000" />
</cars>
```

IF I apply the following XSL to that XML (in an XSL debugger so I can see what's happening), THEN the inline template *match="car"* iterates through all *@model* attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/cars">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

<!-- When applied inline this structure iterates through all @model attributes. -->
  <xsl:template match="car">
    <xsl:value-of select="@model"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**RESULT:**

```
Focus
Golf
Camry
Civic
Prizm
```

Exactly what I want. But now I want to apply that same *xsl:template* structure as a named template via *xsl:call-template* as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/cars">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="car">
    <xsl:call-template name="models"/>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- When applied via call-template, lists one @model attribute, then returns -->
  <xsl:template name="models">
    <xsl:value-of select="@model"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this example with only one *name=* template, the result is the same only because (my XSL debugger shows me that) the XSL repeatedly applies the *xsl:call-template* instruction, NOT because the xsl:template *name="models"* iterates through all *@model* attributes as it did when it was inline.

Can someone please explain why (if you'll permit the analogy) the called XSL "sub-routine" RETURNs after one iteration when it doesn't "fall out" of the loop when it's run inline?

**Please note** that I understand there are explicit XSL looping constructs. And I've already produced the multiple-attributes listings I want with *mode=* templates. Those aren't the answers I'm looking for. My question is why the inline versus been-called behavior of an essentially identical *xsl:template* structure differs depending on whether it's run inline or called. Thx...

Comment: I don;t understand your question: the result is the same in both cases.

Comment: See "In this example with only one name= template, the result is the same only because (my XSL debugger shows me that) the XSL repeatedly applies the xsl:call-template instruction, NOT..." That is, if there were multiple named templates the result becomes a series consisting of one attribute from each named template that's called (a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2...), rather than a list of all models followed by all manufacturers followed by all years (a,a,a,a,a, b,b,b,b,b, etc. The question being why the behavior of the "subroutine" template differs when inline versus called...

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your explanation.

Comment: Don't worry 'bout it then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IF I apply the following XSL to that XML (in an XSL debugger so I can
>   see what's happening), THEN the inline template match="car" iterates
>   through all @model attributes.

No, not exactly.  This is where your internal model of what's happening requires adjustment.

In your first XSLT transformation, the template that matches `car` does not *iterate* through anything.  It *matches* repeatedly.  It is able to match because `<xsl:apply-templates />` appears in the `/cars` template and invokes pattern matching for each of the child nodes (including `car` elements) of `cars` because

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

is really the same as

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
```

Comment: With that in mind can a callable *xsl:template name="thisName"* be constructed to list all *@attributes* without including an explicit looping structure?

Comment: Yes, your second example shows how a called template can be invoked repeatedly.   Alternatively, within a called template that's only called once, you can reinvoke pattern matching via `xsl:template` as a way to process multiple attributes instead of looping over them.  In fact, invoking pattern matching is generally prefered to looping.